# Pythonic way to write a for loop that doesn't use the loop index

Tags: eclipse, for-loop, python

This is to do with the following code, which uses a for loop to generate a series of random offsets for use elsewhere in the program.

The index of this for loop is unused, and this is resulting in the 'offending' code being highlighted as a warning by Eclipse / PyDev

```
def RandomSample(count):    
    pattern = []
    for i in range(count):
        pattern.append( (random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5) )

    return pattern
```

So I either need a better way to write this loop that doesn't need a loop index, or a way to tell PyDev to ignore this particular instance of an unused variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818828/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-python-for-range-loop-without-an-iterator-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
randomSample = [(random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5) for _ in range(count)]
```

Sample output, for `count=10` and assuming that you mean the Standard Library `random()` function:

```
[(-0.07, -0.40), (0.39, 0.18), (0.13, 0.29), (-0.11, -0.15),\
(-0.49, 0.42), (-0.20, 0.21), (-0.44, 0.36), (0.22, -0.08),\
(0.21, 0.31), (0.33, 0.02)]
```

If you really need to make it a function, then you can abbreviate by using a `lambda`:

```
f = lambda count: [(random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5) for _ in range(count)]
```

This way  you can call it like:

```
>>> f(1)
f(1)
[(0.03, -0.09)]
>>> f(2)
f(2)
[(-0.13, 0.38), (0.10, -0.04)]
>>> f(5)
f(5)
[(-0.38, -0.14), (0.31, -0.16), (-0.34, -0.46), (-0.45, 0.28), (-0.01, -0.18)]
>>> f(10)
f(10)
[(0.01, -0.24), (0.39, -0.11), (-0.06, 0.09), (0.42, -0.26), (0.24, -0.44) , (-0.29, -0.30), (-0.27, 0.45), (0.10, -0.41), (0.36, -0.07), (0.00, -0.42)]
>>>
```

you get the idea...

Comment: This just renamed the unused variable to _ and so isn't really any better, unless Eclipse ignores that specially.

Comment: Does PyDev not give the same warning about _ being unused?

Comment: '_' is a dummy variable, Eclipse should not complain, but I don't know, as I have never developed Python on that platform. Good luck, and please let me know if it does complain.

Comment: Nope, _ doesn't get the warning.

Comment: '_' isn't special in any way. Really, Eclipse *should* complain if it does in other cases. Of course, in this case, I feel just ignoring eclipse's complaint is valid.

Comment: _ isn't special by meaning, but it is special by convention (it's accepted as the way to represent an unused loop index). I'd just forgotten about that particular convention.

Comment: @WaffleMatt: Please refer to the post herein which explains the default dummy variables in PyDev.

Comment: Why use lambda if you're going to give the function a name anyway. `def f(count) : return `[(random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5) for _ in range(count)]` is definitely way more pythonic.

Also, this is probably a good candidate for a generator expression (and xrange if we're talking about Python 2).

Comment: Who accepted underscore as "the way to represent an unused loop index" in Python?  Underscore is already frequently used for gettext in Python code, not to mention the last statement return value in the REPL.

Answer (score 18):

Just for reference for ignoring variables in PyDev

By default pydev will ignore following variables

```
['_', 'empty', 'unused', 'dummy']
```

You can add more by passing supression parameters

```
-E, --unusednames  ignore unused locals/arguments if name is one of these values
```

Ref:
http://eclipse-pydev.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.3/PyCheckerLauncher_8java-source.html

Comment: PyDev suppresses warnings for unused variables if they *start with* an underscore. So `_i` would also work.

Comment: You could also add "i=i". This has the advantage that is would work in any development environment regardless of what builtin variable ignores it has.

Answer (score 5):

How about [itertools.repeat](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
import itertools
count = 5
def make_pat():
    return (random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5)
list(x() for x in itertools.repeat(make_pat, count))
```

**Sample output:**

```
[(-0.056940506273799985, 0.27886450895662607), 
(-0.48772848046066863, 0.24359038079935535), 
(0.1523758626306998, 0.34423337290256517), 
(-0.018504578280469697, 0.33002406492294756), 
(0.052096928160727196, -0.49089780124549254)]
```

Comment: As a function: `fn = lambda count: itertools.repeat(lambda: (random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5), count)`

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but here's a potential idea:

```
def RandomSample(count):
    f = lambda: random() - 0.5
    r = range if count < 100 else xrange # or some other number
    return [(f(), f()) for _ in r(count)]
```

Strictly speaking, this is more or less the same as the other answers, but it does two things that look kind of nice to me.

First, it removes that duplicate code you have from writing `random() - 0.5` twice by putting that into a lambda.

Second, for a certain size range, it chooses to use  `xrange()` instead of `range()` so as not to unnecessarily generate a giant list of numbers you're going to throw away. You may want to adjust the exact number, because I haven't played with it at all, I just thought it might be a potential efficiency concern.

Comment: Why not just _always_ use xrange?

Comment: That's a good alternative. I'm making the assumption that creating a generator for only two iterations might be more expensive than creating a list of only two elements. I, of course, have no benchmarks on how expensive generators and lists may or may not be, but somehow I have a feeling that if `xrange(2)` is more efficient than `range(2)` then something is terribly wrong with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way to suppress code analysis errors in PyDev, like this:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_assistants.html

Also, PyDev will ignore unused variables that begin with an underscore, as shown here:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_code_analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while count > 0:
    pattern.append((random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5))
    count -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, random   

def RandomSample2D(npoints, get_random=lambda: random.uniform(-.5, .5)):
    return ((r(), r()) for r in itertools.repeat(get_random, npoints))
```

- uses `random.uniform()` explicitly
- returns an iterator instead of list