# line 1, in <module> F,S = list(map(int,input().split())) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am getting errors about listing
i think its because of some inputs have only one integer

i tried seperating them with map split but it didnt work out

Question:

Enter two integers then compare their values.

The first line of the input consist of a single integer number t which determines the number of tests.

In each of next t lines there are two numbers m and n that are separated by a space character.
sample input:

Input Format:

```
5
9 2
-3 -5
5 28
0 0
19 13
```

sample output:

```
9  is greater than  2
-3  is greater than  -5
5  is smaller than  28
n is equal m:  0
19  is greater than  13
```

my code:

```py
n,m = list(map(int,input().split()))
int(n)
int(m)
if n > m:
   print(n+('is greater than'+m))
if m < n:
   print(m+('is smaller than'+n))
if m > n:
    print(m+('is greater than'+n))
if n < m:
    print(n+('is smaller than'+m))
if n == m:
    print(n+('is equal'+m))
```

Comment: The first line is a single integer. What do you expect `list(map(int,input().split()))` should do with it?

Comment: BTW, `n > m` is equivalent to `m < n`.

Comment: i know but how should i make it right for given format

Comment: Read the first line, convert it to an integer, and store it in a variable `k`. Then run your current code [`k` times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264634/more-pythonic-way-to-run-a-process-x-times). And remove redundant `m < n` and `m > n`

Comment: t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n,m = list(map(int,input().split()))
like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This erros is happening because you try to separate n and m in the first input.
However, the first input should be a loop control bariable.

An example of the code would be:

```
control = int(input("Control variable: "))

for x in range(control):
   n,m = list(map(int, input().split()))

   if n > m:
       print(f'{n} is grater than {m}')
   elif m > n:
       print(f'{m} is grater than {n}')
   else:
       print(f'{n} is equal to {m}')
    
   x += 1
```

after, you can perform a check if the user actually passed two numbers.

Comment: oh thank you
i made it like this and it worked




``` lang-py
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n, m = input().split()
    n = int(n)
    m = int(m)

    if n > m:
       print(n, ' is greater than ', m)
    if n < m:
       print(n, ' is smaller than ', m)
    if n == m:
        print('n is equal m: ', m)
```