# reading multiple webpages using loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I an using a function (movies_from_url) to read movies total 256 from a webpage.  Each page contains 50  movies.  I have to read first 6 pages for this  (5 pages for 250 movies and 6th page for 6 movies).

first url:

http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start=1&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014

Here is my vague idea:

```
def read_m_by_rating(first_year=2005, last_year=2015, top_number=256):
    current_index=1   # current index is start number  of a webpage 
    final_list = []
    for _ in xrange(6):
    url = http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start=current_index&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014
    if top_number==300:
         lis = movies_from_url(url, top_number - current_index + 1)
    else:
         lis = movies_from_url(url, 50)

    final_list.append(lis)
    current_index=+50
    return final_list
```

Comment: *Which* difficulty are you having? Strange code, btw. Try yourself and then ask. We're not here to write full programs for you.

Comment: @ ForceBru, to create each urls.

Comment: you're talking about `for loop here to create  url:` ?

Comment: I think it's a good question. He did provide pseudo code that proves he did some thinking. My suggestion to you is to try and break this into challanges one by one. For now just try and master for loops. You may want to google "loop comprehension". (leave aside the specfics of dynamic-content crawling for now).

Comment: The URL you've provided is not valid. It only works in your browser's session, so trying to access it from a python script will not work unless you submit the form data (your search query) first.

Comment: Just loop through `start` as this: `for o in xrange(20): a_url="http://url.com/?bla=23&start="+str(o)+"&blabla=32"` and use `a_url` then

Comment: This link is broken, you know that right?

Comment: @ Malik Brahimi, I know. I copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using a simple loop over current_index should work.

```
while current_index<256:
    url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start="\
    +str(current_index)+"&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014"
    ...
    ...
    current_index+=50
return final_list
```

Comment: @ Ayush Gupta, This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818828/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-python-for-range-loop-without-an-iterator-variable?rq=1 talks about  doing something x times.

Comment: You need to modify your movies_from_url() so that you get the number of items in "lis" and end the while loop on that basis.