# Difference between range(i+1) and [0]*(i+1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference in these two lines of code in python?

```
for _ in range(i+1):
```

and

```
for _ in [0]*(i+1):
```

Comment: Side-note: `range` is generally considered the idiomatic way to run a loop `n` times while ignoring the iteration value, but if you're trying to squeeze out every last drop of speed, you can do a little better by using `for _ in itertools.repeat(None, i + 1):`, which, like Py3 `range`, behaves as a virtual iterator in this context (values produced on demand, no large temporaries precomputed as in `[0]*(i+1)`), but in addition, doesn't produce any per iteration objects at all (`range` must make brand new `int`s beyond an implementation detail boundary).

Comment: Closely related: [Is it possible to implement a Python for range loop without an iterator variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818828/364696) given that these code snippets are both attempts to perform the task requested in that question.

Answer (score 1):

`range(i+1)` creates an object of class `range` while `[0]*(i+1)` creates a list of `i+1` elements. `range` object will generate an iteration of `i+1` elements, but does not occupy memory space for them.

Using `_` variable on above `range` will generate items from `0` to `i`, while the second code block generates a list of `0` values only.

Comment: `_` is a convention for a "throwaway" variable. You're not supposed to use the value.

Comment: as in OP label: python-3.x

Answer (score 0):

The first line will create a `range` object and the second a `list` object. For example

```
>>> i = 5
>>> print(range(i+1))
range(0, 6)
>>> print([0]*(i+1))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and iterating through them produces

```
>>> for _ in range(i+1):
...     print(_)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
>>> for _ in [0]*(i+1):
...     print(_)
...
0
0
0
0
0
0
```